# Python decode multipart response

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm sending a get http request to a REST webservice. The webservice answers with an multipart response.

The response is split into 2 parts: The first one is a Json message and the other one is the content corresponding to a STL file. Here is an example:

```
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 169

{
    "lightSensitivity": "Average",
    "meshDensity": "Low",
    "nbFaces": 25739,
    "nbVertices": 13597,
    "scanFormatEncoding": "RAW",
    "state": "finished"
}

--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 472032

�Cì��B��|��@��@à�����@޲@��������@ٗ@��u�JcA_�@�x�#��A�|@�H�@��MA�v@��@^��zA�l@à�{�2HA�h@è���r�  AON@�Tߛ�^�AZ.@ø4��?� A2���Aa9?���O�6AK+?��m�vA�&?�4W���S  A�$?Ô����A��>Ð�����A*�>�����A��>�U���jAu�>�@���Z�A��@���BX1;@Aw@�N�BhbJ@~o@�cM�B��P@=]@Û��B8�V@�X@Õ |B��_@5@�8CuBPg@�;@�~nB�)o@�%@àBgB��u@]@�!�`B�r~@�@���YB�a�@ �?�qBSBpO�@l�?�=�LBlc�@��?ÌYFB���@��?þ@BD{�@�?�5�9Bx��@)�?���3BP��@7�?�i-B��@;�?Â]%B4!�@\x?��{B�@Fb?�n�B��@Y?���B�D�@kB?��MB��@!?�{��Ad��@y?�+j�A,�@?�(t�A���@��>����A�@��>�6��A,��@��>äL�AH��@��>�n��AH��@Լ>��AX�@
�>Ì�vA�D�@3[>à�S@�L�@nF>�@�?�%�@�:>�@��H8�@u2>���>�|��@�.>�p��h&�@ (>à����6A�>È��N�AC�=À�#�0AA�=�HA���A��=��U^�z�A��=�|��   Ai�=���G)B���@LP>�X!B�1�@�2>Ø�B좩@\*>�V�B���@��=�&��At��@v�=�C�A]�@5w=ÄYhA���@TC=��;�@,��@�=����?���@�=�^����@R��AN>����B��7@H>È��Bx�D@��=��6�B��L@��=�W��Bp�R@@�=�9�{B��\@(�=��tBPNb@]�=�!�mBpRk@]�=É%gB�1r@ �=��n`B�?z@��=���YBm�@�=æSB,��@h=Ò�LB$L�@�`=�oPFBΌ@�O=��@B�`�@PB=÷�9B���@�:=è~3B|[�@�.=�P[-Bć�@q=�q]%B`��@�
=ÐTB���@���܊�@��;��͘�l�@��;�����(1AĒ;�l�ԦAGz;�x�#���A�r;�(�@�ȔASm;�0J^���AAg;�H�{��AM];�xČ��
A�I;�L͛�آ
Aw%;�\4����A];�����A;Ð���A��:Ìu��AС:����:�AQ�:�0V���-%A:�z
```

Could you tell me how I can decode this response? Currently my code looks like:

```
endpoint = "http://localhost:4000/api/v1/test"
data = {"ip":"1.1.2.3"}
headers = {"Authorization":"Bearer "+ token}
response = requests.get(endpoint,data=data,headers=headers)
# request is OK, now I have to handle the content: decode JSON and save the STL content in a file
```

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for the API you're using? That's definitely binary data, do you know what the API expects you to do with it?

Comment: Have you tried the [`email.mime`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/email.mime.html) module? (The name is a tad misleading since it can be used for decoding any multi-part MIME data, not necessarily from an e-mail).

Comment: @Prune not great advice considering there's a proper way to handle a MIME response.

Comment: Okay; I'll leave this to people more familiar with the paradigm.  Comment deleted.

Comment: @NathanHinchey: I'm using the API requests but I didn't see any way to decode the response in the documentation :/
I can get the content as a text or as bytes but it doesn't help :/

Comment: @Maxime What API are you using?

Comment: I m using requests. But as I'm blokked, I m opened to use another library

Comment: I'm using requets and have to handle a similar case, did you manage to do so with requests ?